# Compare columns of duplicated numbers and populate a fourth column

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I have seen questions on here that are similar but not the exact issue I am having. It is below and please forgive me if I don't explain this well.
I have 3 columns.
**Column A** is a list of file numbers in our system. This column contains many duplicates and is 172522 rows.
**Column B** is that same list of file numbers, but with the duplicates removed. This is 28858 rows.
**Column C** is a list of Reference numbers corresponds with Column B exactly, i.e. C2 is a reference number for B2 and so on

I need a query that pulls the reference number from C and places in it column D, for as many times as the file number occurs in Column A. So I get a list of duplicated filenos with their corresponding duplicated Reference numbers
Is this possible?

Comment: Formula ok? `=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$28858,2)` where the range is the range of your column B/c

Comment: @xQbert you will want to use the fourth criterion of `False` in the vlookup as I doubt it is sorted.  `=VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$C,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Both excellent comments. Thanks for improving the response!

Answer (score 1):

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$28858,2, False)`

Vlookup takes a value and finds it in a "range" and then allows you to take another value in that range and return it.  In this case, the 2nd column of range B,C.  Though i believe the first column in the range is always the one it has to look through.

[image]

Comment: yes since it is not an array formula and it stops as soon as it finds true, it does not matter.

Comment: @xQbert-That gave me the results I was looking for! Thank you.